# StateListDrawable in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, keyboard, textview, popupwindow, statelistdrawable

I am trying to set a StateList drawable for the background of a textview (as a key preview popup for a keyboard).  When the user presses down on the key, the drawable's state is set to long_pressable if the key has popup characters.

When testing on a Droid Incredible running 2.3.4, the code runs as expected.  However, when running the code on a Galaxy Nexus the state does not change until I move from one key to the next.

To try to find the source of the problem, I set the background of the key to be the drawable for my TextView background (the statelistdrawable).  Like expected, the state would not set correctly on key press for ICS, but did work on Gingerbread.

Any ideas?

(By the way, the TextView is displayed in a PopupWindow)

Thanks